# Flow doesn't invoke assignment rules via apex

Tags: visual-workflow, assignment-rules, invocable-method

I seem to have found some strange behavior in the Flow tool.  I've created a flow that does some record queries/updates, and then invokes the below class:

```
public class LeadAssignInvocable {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds) {
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;          
        Lead Leads=[select Id from lead where lead.id in :LeadIds];
        system.debug(LeadIds);
        system.debug(Leads);
        Leads.setOptions(dmo);
        try{
            Database.update(Leads, dmo);
        } catch(exception e){
            system.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        system.debug([SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Name FROM Lead WHERE lead.id in :LeadIds]);
   }
}
```

When I run this snippet via anonymous apex to manually invoke the apex, everything works fine:

```
Lead l = new Lead();
l.LastName = 'TestCC';
l.Company = 'TestCC';
insert l;

List<Id> LeadIds = new List<Id>{l.Id};
LeadAssignInvocable.LeadAssign(LeadIds);
```

But when invoked by the Flow, the assignment rules don't change the owner.  I've confirmed that the flow is firing the class debug statements, and set the lead id, and no error is occurring.  The lead assignment rules simply don't take effect.

FWIW, the flow is an "after insert" flow.  But it seems to have the correct record id and the invocable method is definitely running after the flow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why assignment rules did not execute when invoked by a flow?**

The invocable apex method within the flow didn't invoke the assignment rules because of two reasons:

- Flow elements (for *Create* & *Update*) do not have options to specify *Database.DMLOptions* (`assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true`) at the moment. *This was probably one of the reasons why you chose to have the invocable apex code*.
- Assignment rules don't get invoked during recursive save. Refer to [apex triggers and order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm#!).

> During a recursive save, Salesforce skips steps 9 (assignment rules)
> through 19 (roll-up summary field in the grandparent record).

Based on your description, your flow seems to first perform DML (*update*) on the lead records and then pass them to the invocable apex method for further processing. All of this will run in a single transaction. When the flow update element is executing, point #1 mentioned above (*i.e. lack of option to set DMLOptions value*) will prevent the assignment rules from execution. After this, when the invocable apex method executes, the DML within the apex will be considered as a recursive save and hence, assignment rules will not be run.

*If you want to test this out, you can modify your invocable apex to query & include few records which did not actually trigger the flow. For these records, the DML in the invocable apex will not be seen as recursive save and hence, the assignment rules will execute. Within the invocable apex method, ensure that you update these records to satisfy the assignment rule criteria (in addition to setting the DMLOptions value)*

**Why assignment rules seem to work when anonymous code snippet is executed?**

Most likely the assignment rules were not run due to the invocable apex method execution, but because the records created by insert DML must have satisfied the assignment rule criteria. The entire piece of anonymous code will execute under a single transaction and hence, the DML inside the invocable apex method call will be considered as a recursive save. You can test this out simply by commenting out the invocable apex call or create few scenario based test data & execute them. *Also, note that there could be other scenarios or set up in your org that might have contributed to this*.

**So, why does it work when you moved all the functionality into invocable apex method and called it via an scheduled action in a process builder?**

Immediate actions in process builder run within a single transaction, while scheduled actions run in a separate transaction ([ref](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_transactions.htm&type=5)). So, in your final solution, the DML performed inside the invocable apex runs under a separate transaction and will not be considered as a recursive save. Hence, the assignment rules will execute without any problem. *Although I've not tried this, I'm sure that if you invoked the apex method within an immediate action, the assignment rules will not run.*

---

*Schedulable lightning flows have been introduced in Winter'20 release. Unlike process builder, it only facilitates running the flow at a specific time of a day or week; making it suitable for daily or weekly jobs. Hopefully, if future release includes scheduling a flow similar to scheduled actions in process builder, then you might be able to achieve this functionality in lightning flow.*

Comment: You are correct.  Moving the record update into the Apex caused the assignment rules to fire.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this by moving all the logic to Apex and having it invoked by Process Builder instead of Flow.  I used this article, which mentioned some strangeness with the order of operations and used a time-based action to side-step it:

https://automationchampion.com/tag/run-lead-assignment-rules-for-flow/

Edit: importantly, I moved the record updates into the apex as well.  This made it a single-action transaction, which skipped any oddness about assignment rules not re-running.